# Java class methods undefined

Tags: java

I am getting an error in Eclipse for simple class methods like the String spit method and LinkedList peek and poll methods. I can't figure out why this is happening since these are standard methods for those classes. Here are the exact error messages I am getting:

"The method `split(String, int)` is undefined for the type `String`"

"The method `poll()` is undefined for the type `LinkedList<String>`"

"The method `peek()` is undefined for the type `LinkedList<String>`"

Here is the section of code these are being used in:

```
void clearMissions(){
    while(missions.peek() != null){
        missions.remove();
    }
}

private String getMission(){
    return missions.poll();
}

...

for(int i = 0;s.hasNextLine();i++){
        String temp = s.nextLine();
        String[] command = temp.split(" ",2);
        try{
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("FOLLOW LINE")){
                missions.add(temp);
            }
...
```

Comment: Q: Exactly what JRE is Eclipse configured for?  Q: What version of Eclipse are you using?  Q: What happens when you try an explicit `import java.util.LinkedList`?  Q: What does auto-complete show you for your String and LinkedList variables' methods?

Comment: Please report how it is defined the "missions" list. If you have defined it like *List<SomeClass>* you will not able to use the LinkedList's methods.

Answer (score -1):

Most the time it comes because you need to import those libraries under which these function are defined.

inside your source code you need to import libraries like this

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
```

Similarly for other libraries too

Edit: String don't need any import may be some configuration problem with your eclipse

Comment: That's not a valid import, and `String` never needs to be imported.

Comment: @chrylis i guess i imported linked list and didn't mentioned anything about string above